# How can I merge tables and get the most recent row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to track the movement of guests who stay at a hotel (hypothetical). Thus, I can created 3 tables.

1. guests = People who are staying at a hotel
2. room_guest_is_in = Where the guest was seen
3. rooms = Specific information about the room

guests

```
guest_id | name
1        | Bob
2        | Mike
```

rooms

```
room_id | room_name
1       | Casino
2       | Resturant
3       | Spa
```

room_guest_is_in

```
guest_id is a foreign key from the guests table.
last updated is the last time we recorded them in the room.
room_id is a foreign key from the room table

rguest_id | guest_id | roomd_id | last_updated
1         | 1        | 3        | 2019-03-18 10:04:16
2         | 1        | 3        | 2019-03-18 11:19:34
3         | 1        | 2        | 2019-03-18 12:11:36
4         | 2        | 1        | 2019-03-18 12:03:20
```

---

From the data above you can see Bob was at the Spa twice at `2019-03-17 10:04:16` and at `2019-03-17 11:19:34` and at the resturant once.

**My question:** I want to select all the rooms bob has been in. However, if Bob has been in a room more than once, it should only show the latest entry for that room. That means a room doesn't show up more than once in the select statement

I **want** results to be like:

```
guest_id | name | room_name  | last updated
1        | Bob  | Spa        | 2019-03-17 11:19:34
1        | Bob  | Gym        | 2019-03-17 12:11:36
```

I am getting results like:

```
guest_id | name | room_name  | last updated
1        | Bob  | Spa        | 2019-03-17 11:19:34
1        | Bob  | Gym        | 2019-03-17 12:11:36
1        | Bob  | Spa        | 2019-03-17 10:04:16
```

My SQL:

```
SELECT guests.guest_id, guests.name, rooms.room_name, room_guest_is_in.last_updated
FROM guests
INNER JOIN room_guest_is_in ON guests.guest_id = room_guest_is_in.guest_id
INNER JOIN rooms.room_id ON room_guest_is_in.room_id = rooms.room_id
WHERE guests.guest_id = 1
ORDER BY room_guest_is_in.last_updated DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just need to `GROUP BY` to get the maximum date:

```
SELECT guests.guest_id, guests.name, rooms.room_name, MAX(room_guest_is_in.last_updated) AS last_updated
FROM guests
INNER JOIN room_guest_is_in ON guests.guest_id = room_guest_is_in.guest_id
INNER JOIN rooms.room_id ON room_guest_is_in.room_id = rooms.room_id
WHERE guests.guest_id = 1
GROUP BY guests.guest_id, guests.name, rooms.room_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated subquery

```
SELECT a.guest_id, a.name, c.room_name, b.last_updated
FROM guests a
INNER JOIN room_guest_is_in b ON a.guest_id = b.guest_id
INNER JOIN rooms c ON b.room_id = b.room_id
   WHERE a.guest_id = 1 and 
   b.last_updated in 
      (select max(b1.last_updated)
          from room_guest_is_in b1 where b.room_id=b1.room_id and 
          b1.guest_id=b.guest_id)
ORDER BY b.last_updated DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is giving the result which you have written above I think this will give the expected result.. if you need something else you can ask..

```
SELECT top 1 guests.guest_id, guests.name, rooms.room_name, room_guest_is_in.last_updated
FROM guests
INNER JOIN room_guest_is_in ON guests.guest_id = room_guest_is_in.guest_id
INNER JOIN rooms.room_id ON room_guest_is_in.room_id = rooms.room_id
WHERE guests.guest_id = 1
ORDER BY room_guest_is_in.last_updated DESC
```